# Bootstrap DatePicker format mm/yyyy set max month

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using bootstrap datepicker in format mm/yyyy, but I can't set max month. My code is like this:

```
$('#mesVigencia').datepicker({
    format: "mm/yyyy",
    startView: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
    language: 'pt-BR'
});
```

How can I set max month like current month?

Comment: what do you mean max month? december?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please add what you have tried to the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set MinDate and maxDate property of datetimepicker in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861864/how-to-set-mindate-and-maxdate-property-of-datetimepicker-in-bootstrap)

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed max month is the last month that can be selectable, date greater than that must be disabled

Comment: Thank you all, I solved this issue using endDate attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `endDate: "0m"` check my sample,

```js
$('#mesVigencia').datepicker({
    format: "mm/yyyy",
    startView: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
    language: 'pt-BR',
    endDate: "0m"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="mesVigencia"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `maxDate:` in the object

```
$('#mesVigencia').datepicker({
    format: "mm/yyyy",
    startView: "months",
    minViewMode: "months",
    language: 'pt-BR',
    maxDate: new Date("2017-11-00")
});
```

Use `new Date("2017-11-00")` if you want to set november as the max month